# NPM outdated shows nothing

Tags: npm, npm-outdated

I use npm 6.11.3. Now I want to updated the local dev dependencies.

But when I use `npm outdated` the terminal shows nothing. But I know there are updates available for installed dependencies.

Does anyone know, what I'm doing wrong?